# e commerce discount coupon riddle

Tags: logical-deduction

This is a question from [technothlon 2014 paper](http://technothlon.techniche.org/downloads/prevpapers)
[image]

I couldnot understand how are they making the sequences.

Comment: yeah there was an error in Q2 which the exam board realised. there is no answer and the question was nullified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1:

> B

Q2:

There is no answer, and the exam board realised there was an error and nullified the question. Thanks to @ffao for telling me in chat.

---

The table is an alphabet version of the times tables, where numbers over 26 just start again from 1 (27=A, 28=B, etc.)

Basically you have the times tables:

```
1 2 3
2 4 6
3 6 9
```

etc.

The next step is to modulo 26 all the numbers:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
2  4  6  8  10 12 14
3  6  9  12 15 18 21
4  8  12 16 20 24 2
5  10 15 20 25 4  9
6  12 18 24 4  10 16
7  14 21 2  9  16 23
```

Then A1Z26 gives the table:

```
A B C D E F G 
B D F H J L N 
C F I L O R U 
D H L P T X B 
E J O T Y D I 
F L R X D J P 
G N U B I P W
```

So the diagonals (top left to bottom right) is basically the A1Z26 equivalent of the square numbers. A=1, D=4, I=9 etc.

But the question is pretty wordy. What it is telling you to do is basically fibonacci the numbers: So the diagonal pattern is

> A, A+D, A+D+I, etc.

So the pattern is (mod 26 so it can be converted back to the alphabet). The full pattern is apparently the ['square pyramidal numbers'](https://oeis.org/A000330) according to OEIS.

> 1, 5, 14, 4, 3, 13, 10

Which is

> A E N D C M J

Q1

The 7th term is

> J, answer B.

Q2

4th term = D, but none of the solutions start with D.

Thanks @ffao for telling me the exam board realised this and gave marks to everyone for it:

[image]

Comment: If the options are valid then A certain number can be decoded to more than one letter

Comment: @Talal_Sharaa sorry are you talking about Q2?

Comment: yeah I just noticed that in Q2 option a for example is IHSIR and the number is 46645 then both H & S are 6, how so? that's also true for other options

Comment: @Talal_Sharaa i like your thinking, but sadly the question was wrong and the exam board realised this. see update

Comment: Thank you for a clear and complete solution.can you please share what made you think that it has something to do with times table.