# a bumping question

Tags: logical-deduction

This is a question from [technothlon 2014 paper](http://technothlon.techniche.org/downloads/prevpapers)

[image]

I tried hard to solve this question but no progress.I think that some more information is needed.

Comment: If you are really stuck on a problem, you should say what you have tried so far and what results you've gotten. Otherwise a less charitable person might note that your [entire](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52435/e-commerce-discount-coupon-riddle) PSE [history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52424/technothlon-2014-question) consists of asking questions taken directly from the 2014 Technothlon with no effort put into posting them beyond cut and paste, and suspect you're just farming for rep points. *\*cough\**

Comment: I think I have an answer, but some of the puzzle wording is ambiguous. When it says "He goes around and asks" in the last paragraph, does that refer to Midhul or Mayank?

Comment: @MikeQ Presumably Midhul, since the story is told from his point of view ("Midhul and seven of his friends ...")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three questions are solvable with the information given. The answers are:

> 3. C. Saicharan bumped 3 players.
>  4. C. Midhul bumped 3 players.
>  5. B. Saicharan bumped Mayank, but not Kenil.

**Explanation**

There are 8 total players, and nobody can bump their self or their teammate. That means a given player has bumped at most 6 distinct other players. Letting someone's score be the number of distinct players they bumped, we can represent everyone's scores as an 8-element multiset, with integer values between 0 and 6. Other than Midhul, the remaining 7 players had unique scores. Therefore, one value is repeated in the multiset, and it is Midhul's score.

> Bumping is a two-way relationship. That means we can represent the interactions of the players bumping each other as a graph. Each vertex represents a player. An edge represents that two players bumped each other.
>  
>  Then we assign vertices colors to represent teams. The colors themselves don't matter, as long as we maintain that teammates do not bump each other. Begin with the player with score 6 (who bumped everyone except for themselves and their teammate) and the player with score 0, who must be teammates. Then the players with scores 5 and 1, and so on.
>  [image]
>  *(For the colorblind: A, H = blue. B, G = green. C, F = purple. D, E = red.)*
>  
>  You can see that two players have a score of 3. One of these is Midhul.
>
>  His teammate (the other node with the same color) must be Saicharan. We can see that both of them have a score of 3, which means they both bumped 3 other players.
>  
>  From the diagram we see that Midhul and Saicharan bumped the same 3 players, who were all on different teams. If Midhul bumped Mayank, then Saicharan also bumped Mayank. And if they bumped Mayank, that means they did *not* bump Mayank's teammate, who is Kenil.  Therefore Saicharan bumped Mayank but not Kenil. (Thanks [Talal_Sharaa](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37156/talal-sharaa) for noticing this.)

Comment: The answer for the last question is either: b)  or c) because saicharan bumbed into a car of each color... The key answer for this exam says it's b... And I think this is because they stated that midhul bumbed into manyak so one of those is manyak, and kenil is not one of them because they are from different teams, so the answer is indeed (B) I hope my comment is clear :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I didn't know the answer key was accessible.